# Jaguar Mk 9,Power steering

Tags: maintenance, jaguar

Can I mix Dexron 2 & 3 Power steering fluids in the system? on my 1959 Mk 9 Jaguar

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you'll be fine. The Dexron 3 fluids came along after the Dexron 2 as a more refined formula, so it is backwards compatible with the Dexron 2 fluids.